# 1400 year old virgin?

Tags: quran, hadith, prophet-muhammad, maryam

Reading Quran [19:27,28](https://quran.com/19/27) Christians and Jews encounter something that raises alarms.

> Then she brought him to her people, carrying him. They said, "O Mary, you have certainly done a thing unprecedented. O sister of **Aaron**, your father was not a man of evil, nor was your mother unchaste."

The same alarms were raised in Najran, as we see recorded in [Sahih Muslim #5326](https://sunnah.com/muslim/38/13)

> When I came to Najran, they (the Christians of Najran) asked me: You read "O sister of Harun" (i.e. Hadrat Maryam) in the Qur'an, whereas Moses was born much before Jesus. When I came back to Allah's Messenger (may peace be upon him) I asked him about that, whereupon he said: The (people of the old age) used to give names (to their persons) after the names of Apostles and pious persons who had gone before them.

The 2 problems the Christians faced in this passage is that...

1. They understood the Quran saying that Aaron's sister (who lived hundreds of years before the birth of Jesus) was the same person as the Theotokos, making Dei Genetrix about 1400 years old when giving birth to the True God.
2. They seen that the author of the Quran confused Maryam the sister of Moses with Mary the Mother of God.

The first being problematic to their christian faith, in the understanding that the Light of the world was born of a young woman, but the greatest miracle in fertility & life.

The second being problematic to the legitimacy of the Quran, therefore the legitimacy of the prophetic career of Muhammad.

Luckily Muhammad explains the situation, saying that it was simply the way people were named in the time, simply a metaphor.

Sounds like a closed case, but not yet, there is no evidence (I am able to find) showing in that time (of the Mother of God) where an ordinary person would be named "sister of (pious ancient person)". (Judea preferred)

If there is no evidence, then I can only see 4 situations.

1. This particular part of the Quran is **miraculously** the **only** part of history where this is recorded (600 years after the era).
2. There is evidence **fully satisfying** the pending evidence request of many Christians for hundreds of years, making it public and finally settling the centuries long evidence request.
3. The Hadith quoted is unreliable and the mother of the Lamb of God was truly very old at the birth of the God Incarnate.
4. Or there is simply an error in the infallible word of God, making Muhammad a fraud.

My question is if there's any evidence backing up the metaphor explained by Muhammad.

Comment: Could you edit this in a way that makes it sound less like a polemical Christian pamphlet?

Comment: you have a mistake at "sister of (pious ancient person)", because the hadith says not that she is named as sister of ancient person, but her brother harun was named so when he was born.

Comment: I can not edit it to look less than a "polemical Christian pamphlet" because most of them titles of Jesus were used long before Islam. I will change "light of nations" because it was used long after Islam in the document lumen gentium, in the second Vatican council.

Comment: I used "sister of (pious ancient person)" as the direct example used in the Quran, the people of Najran found it unique so I want other examples to prove this practice actually existed, and the Quran is not the only example of it.

Comment: Related if not a duplicate of https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/33630/13438

Answer (score 11):

The Quranic verse [19:28](https://quran.com/19/28) is:

يَا **أُخْتَ** هَارُونَ مَا كَانَ أَبُوكِ امْرَأَ سَوْءٍ وَمَا كَانَتْ أُمُّكِ بَغِيًّا
Ya **okhta** haroona ma kana abooki imraa sawin wama kanat ommuki baghiyyan

The Arabic word used here is similar to the Hewbrew word אָחוֹת (achowth), its usage is explained in *Gesenius' Hebrew-Chaldee Lexicon* as:

Source: [Blue Letter Bible](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=H269&t=KJV), scan on [archive.org](https://archive.org/stream/hebrewchaldeelex00geseuoft#page/30/mode/2up)

[image]

Its similar to the Arabic Akhi (brother) which also has cognates in Hebrew where they include tribal relations and similarity of character:

Source: [Blue Letter Bible](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=H251&t=KJV),  Scan on [archive.org](https://archive.org/stream/hebrewchaldeelex00geseuoft#page/26/mode/2up)
[image]

---

From the NT, there seems to be evidence that Mary is related to the descendants of Aaron, brother of Moses, and it could be that the people referred to that:

> [Luke 1:5](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%201%3A5&version=KJV) There was in the days of Herod, the king of Judaea, a
>   certain priest named Zacharias, of the course of Abia: and his wife
>   **was of the daughters of Aaron, and her name was Elisabeth**.
>
> [Luke 1:35](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%201%3A35-36&version=KJV) And the angel answered and said unto her, The Holy
>   Ghost shall come upon thee, and the power of the Highest shall
>   overshadow thee: therefore also that holy thing which shall be born of
>   thee shall be called the Son of God.
>
> [Luke 1:36](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%201%3A35-36&version=KJV) And, behold, **thy cousin Elisabeth**, she hath also
>   conceived a son in her old age: and this is the sixth month with her,
>   who was called barren.

I understand that this is a valid interpretation among Christian scholars, though some may disagree with it:

From [Elliot's commentary to the Bible for English readers](http://biblehub.com/commentaries/ellicott/luke/1.htm):

> Taking the word in its usual sense, it would imply that either the
>   **father or the mother of Mary had been of the house of Aaron**, or that
>   the mother of Elizabeth had been of the house of David.
>
> The scanty notices in the Gospels are (1) that she was a “cousin,” or
>   more generally a “kinswoman,” of Elizabeth, and may, **therefore, have
>   been, by her parentage, wholly or in part of the daughters of Aaron**.

From [Expositor's Greek Testament](http://biblehub.com/commentaries/egt/luke/1.htm):

> Luke 1:36. καὶ ἰδού, introducing a reference to Elizabeth’s case to
>   help Mary’s faith.—συγγενίς, late form for συγγενής (T.R.), **a blood
>   relation, but of what degree not indicated, suggesting that Mary
>   perhaps belonged to the tribe of Levi**.—γήρει: Ionic form of dative for
>   γήρᾳ (T.R.). Hellenistic Greek was an eclectic language, drawing from
>   all dialects as from the poets, turning their poetic expressions to
>   the uses of prose.—καλουμένη: Elizabeth is described as one who is
>   still being called barren, though six months gone in pregnancy,
>   because people have had no means of knowing her state.

From [Meyer's NT Commentary](http://biblehub.com/commentaries/meyer/luke/1.htm):

> συγγενίς] The nature of this relationship, which is not at variance
>   with John 1:36, although questioned by Schleiermacher and others, is
>   wholly unknown. It is, however, **possible that Mary was of the stock of
>   Levi** (so Faustus the Manichean in Augustine, c. Faust. xxiii. 9; and
>   recently, Schleiermacher, Schr. d. Luk. p. 26; Hilgenfeld, Ewald,
>   Gesch. Chr. p. 177, and others), as the Test. XII. Patr. p. 542 makes
>   the Messiah proceed from the stock of Judah (Joseph) and (comp. p.
>   546) from the stock of Levi.[25]

---

Secondly, the Quran contains an account of the life of Mary before Jesus's birth and states that she was dedicated to the Temple and raised under guardianship of the [Kohen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kohen):

> [Quran 3:35](https://quran.com/3/35) [Mention, O Muhammad], when the wife of 'Imran said,
>   "My Lord, indeed I have pledged to You what is in my womb, consecrated
>   [for Your service], so accept this from me. Indeed, You are the
>   Hearing, the Knowing."
>
> [Quran 3:36](https://quran.com/3/36) But when she delivered her, she said, "My Lord, I
>   have delivered a female." And Allah was most knowing of what she
>   delivered, "And the male is not like the female. And I have named her
>   Mary, and I seek refuge for her in You and [for] her descendants from
>   Satan, the expelled [from the mercy of Allah ]."
>
> [Quran 3:37](https://quran.com/3/37) So her Lord accepted her with good acceptance and
>   caused her to grow in a good manner and put her in the care of
>   Zechariah. Every time Zechariah entered upon her in the prayer
>   chamber, he found with her provision. He said, "O Mary, from where is
>   this [coming] to you?" She said, "It is from Allah . Indeed, Allah
>   provides for whom He wills without account."

Although this account is not present in the canonical books of the New Testament (as far as I am aware), its referred to in Catholic and Eastern Orthodox tradition and in some books of the apocrypha.

Wikipedia on the [Presentation of Mary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_Mary):

> The account of the Presentation of the Blessed Virgin Mary in the
>   Temple is principally based on the Protoevangelium of James, which has
>   been dated by historians prior to the year 200 AD. The story relates
>   that in thanksgiving for the birth of their daughter, Mary, Joachim
>   and Anne decide to consecrate her to God, and bring her, at the age of
>   three years, to the temple in Jerusalem. Mary’s presentation in the
>   temple draws parallels to that of the prophet Samuel, whose mother
>   Hannah, like Anne was also thought to be barren, and who offered her
>   child as a gift to God at Shiloh.
>
> Mary remained in the Temple until her twelfth year, at which point
>   she was assigned to Joseph as guardian. According to Coptic tradition,
>   her father Joachim died when Mary was six years old and her mother
>   when Mary was eight. While the story is a legend with no foundation
>   in history, the point is to show that even in her childhood Mary was
>   completely dedicated to God. It is from this account that arose the
>   feast of Mary's Presentation.

So it could be that the people referred to her as a sister of Aaron because of her link to the Priestly order, and her dedication and worship in the Temple, a similar disposition to Aaron.

---

[Tafsir Al Qurtubi](http://www.altafsir.com/Tafasir.asp?tMadhNo=0&tTafsirNo=5&tSoraNo=19&tAyahNo=28&tDisplay=yes&UserProfile=0&LanguageId=1) narrates the following views present in Islamic tradition on the relation between Aaron and Mary:

> فقيل: هو هارون أخو موسى؛ والمراد من كنا نظنها مثل هارون في العبادة
>   تأتي بمثل هذا. قيل: على هذا كانت مريم من ولد هارون أخي موسى فنسبت إليه
>   بالأخوة لأنها من ولده؛ كما يقال للتميمي: يا أخا تميم، وللعربي يا أخا
>   العرب. وقيل: كان لها أخ من أبيها اسمه هارون؛ لأن هذا الاسم كان كثيراً
>   في بني إسرائيل تبركاً باسم هارون أخي موسى، وكان أمثل رجل في بني
>   إسرائيل
>
> Some said, the Aaron here is  Aaron, the brother of Moses. The meaning
>   is that "we took her worship and service (to the Temple) as similar to
>   Aaron, then how could she do that?" Some said that she was called
>   sister of Aaron because she was of his descendants ... Some said that
>   Mary had a (step) brother from a father who was named Aaron, and that
>   the name was common among the tribes of Israel because of Aaron's
>   piety, and this other Aaron was also well known and exemplary devout person of the Children of Israel.

Comment: The original Greek used in the NT does not give a specific relation between Mary and Elizabeth, giving NO evidence of common ancestry to Aaron.

Comment: It mentions a relation, though is not specific. [Greek breakdown](http://biblehub.com/interlinear/luke/1-36.htm), details on the word [syggenḗs](http://biblehub.com/greek/4773.htm). That does not change the argument, she was still related to Elizabeth and hence to Aaron.

Comment: @aaaa Greek isn't the original language of the NT so this might already be an error of transmission.

Comment: This tafsir might also be good to add: http://altafasir.com/al-quran/surat/19/maryam/28/razi

Comment: Note Hebrews 7:14 explicitly clearing this situation of "Levi vs Judah" before Islam existed, not forgetting the beginning of the gospel according to St Mathew "the son of David".

Comment: I am confused why there was additional commentaries of this part of the Quran produced when the Muhammad made a very straightforward explanation already.

Comment: @aaa The Hadith clarifies that Mary was not the literal sister of Aaron and Moses and that names were given linking to ancient Prophets and Righteous people (Israel, House of David, daughters of Aaron etc.) All the given views of tradition fit the wording of the hadith, Mary could have been directly given the name linking her to Aaron Brother of Moses (because of kinship or similtitude), she could actually have a half brother named Aaron who in turn could have been named after the brother of Moses, there could have been another Aaron active at the time who Mary was similar to in devotion.

Comment: Since she is given the name of this other "Aaron" as a comparison of piety, why doesn't the Quran, a detailed book (16:49) go into more detail about this man? Why didn't Muhammad give the (even simpler) explanation of "Another Aaron" ? We know from Jewish-christian texts (before Islam) that Mary was not a descendant of Aaron. All logic points to the author of the Quran confusion the 2 Maryams & Muhammad inventing a naming tradition that only has no (specific) example in history.

Comment: @aaa The Quran is very concise and not elaborate at all in that sense, you are misinterpreting the verse. You can choose to disagree with it but I've quoted Christian scholars above who think that Mary was a descendant of Aaron. Further the Quran clearly mentions the Jews not even entering Jerusalem in the time of Moses, and the temple being built by Solomon, and Mary being consecrated in the temple ... so there is no confusion in the Quran. Stack Exchange is not for debates, apologetics or preaching ... I've given the Islamic view with supporting evidence, you are free to disagree with it.

Comment: I can accept that mary was called a sister of aaron and child of imran as a metaphor, but the Quranic verses 3:35-37 are literally describing the wife of imran giving birth to mary the mother of jesus. Is that a metaphor too?

Comment: @UbaidHassan 
As my answer states, it is possible that Mary actually had a brother named Aaron and her father was named Imran, and these three are distinct from the father and brother of the Prophet Musa despite having the same name. The people used to give their children names of notables from their past, as is also seen in Muslim societies, e.g. you may find someone named Muhammad with a father named Abdullah, and you may find a woman named Maryam with a son named Isa. This does not make them the same person as the prophets.

Comment: @umH thank you for the response, but dont  sources outside the Quran refer to mary's father as joachim? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joachim, is there any solid evidence(not quran) to show that mary's father was actually named Imran/amram ?(sorry if this is too much trouble)

Comment: @UbaidHassan 
It is not that straightforward as the only alternate source is the Christian tradition, and they do not have a consensus on the name of Mary's father. One position is that the name is not known. Another position is that he was named Joachim (يؤاقيم) as cited in apocrypha, however it is of dubious authenticity. Another opinion is that his name was Eli \ Heli based on the genealogy in [Luke](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke+3%3A23%E2%80%9338&version=KJV). Muslim historians have cited that he was named Imran bin Mathan (عمران بن ماثان).

Answer (score 1):

Just to add additional information to above answer:

> Mughira b. Shu'ba reported:
>
> When I came to Najran, they (the Christians of Najran) asked me: You
>   read "O sister of Harun" (i.e. Hadrat Maryam) in the Qur'an, whereas
>   Moses was born much before Jesus. When I came back to Allah's
>   Messenger (ﷺ) I asked him about that, whereupon he said: The (people
>   of the old age) used to give names (to their persons) after the names
>   of Apostles and pious persons who had gone before them..‏
>
> ***Reference : Sahih Muslim 2135
>
>   In-book reference : Book 38, Hadith 13
>
>   USC-MSA web (English) reference : Book 25, Hadith 5326 (deprecated
>   numbering scheme)***